# Rails select_tag onchange ajax request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to make a form that adds elements to the form after certain  elements have been selected. For example, After a user selects a country, I want there to be an ajax call where all of the regions/states associated with that country are found, and then inserted into a select element into the form. Then, once a user selects a region/state, the same process will take place and another element will be added to the form in reponse to the selected value. As a side note, I want to do this all unobtrusively.So far, I have this in my view:

```
<%= form_tag(find_school_path, :method=>'get', :class => 'form-horizontal', :id => 'find_by_country_form') do %>

    <%= label_tag :country_selection, "Country" %>
    <%= select_tag :country_selection, options_from_collection_for_select(@countries, :id, :name), :prompt => "Country" %>

<% end %>
```

Then inside of that view's javascript file I handle the ajax call upon selection of a country:

```
$('#country_selection').change(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "find/country_selection",
    type: "GET",
    data: {'country=' + $('#country_selection option:selected').value() },
  })
});
```

Then, inside of my controller in which the above `url:` routes to I have:

```
def country_selection
    @country = Country.find(params[:country])
    @regions = @country.regions

    respond_to do |format|
       format.js {  }
    end
end
```

Lastly, in my country_selection.js.erb file I have:

```
$('#country_selection').after('<%= label_tag :region_selection, "State/Region" %><%= select_tag :region_selection, options_from_collection_for_select(@regions, :id, :name), :prompt => "State/Region" %>');
```

I have not gotten this to work. I am not even sure I am doing this the right way. When I hit select and change the option, nothing on the page changes.

**SOLUTION**

My code was fundamently fine, but the '.change' event was not being recognized. I change it to '.live('change', function() {...})' and it worked just fine.

Comment: why you have if else in the respond_to block???

Comment: Instead of using `$('#country_selection option:selected').value()` use $(this).value()... And in your country_selection.js.erb can you try writing just alert('I am here') and check whether you getting alert or not?

Comment: I have been playing with it and its just strange. I tried putting an alert inside `$('#country_selection').change(function() { alert('hello'); });` and nothing happend. However, when I run that piece of code in the console, it works. So, I though that my file might not be loading. Then, to test this, all I put in the javascript file for the view was `alert('in the js file for the view')` and it worked. For some reason, this: `$('#country_selection').change(function() {alert('hello') });` is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the tidiest code I have seen, but I see nothing wrong with it fundamentally.

I would throw some alerts in there so you can narrow down where the problem is.  You could put one in the change function to make sure that is getting hit, you could add one to the country_selection.js.erb to make sure that is getting hit.  This will help a bit.

I would also change the country_selection.js.erb to render a partial inside a div container where you want the new select to be, that way you can put that code into a partial and it will be a bit tidier.  You can just pass a parameter to the partial that would be the selected country.

Comment: Great. You were right. For some reason the 'change' event was not being recognized. I changed it to `'.live('change', function() { ... } );` and the code worked just fine.

Comment: If you have ajax calls that have already happened, the change event might have been lost.  If you are using a current jquery version, try .on instead of .live (it's the replacement).