# How to write a condition when using select_tag in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a task of generating reports where we will have a drop down list displaying 3 fields A, B and C. These A, B, C are models. If we select A it has to list all the details of A. (Note that we are not saving reports.)
For this i have created a html page with drop down as:

```
<%= select_tag 'report',options_for_select([["A", "a"], ["B", "b"], ["C", "c"]]),include_blank: true, class: 'form-control' %>
```

Is this right way to represent? And how can I write the condition if 'A' is selected or 'B'?

Comment: You need to create ajax request for it. Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948913/rails-select-tag-onchange-ajax-request

Comment: @bunty - Is there a rails way other than AJAX and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

View:

```
<%= form_tag(controller: "YY", action: "XX", method: "get", class: "form-control") do %>
   <%= select_tag 'report',options_for_select([["A", "a"], ["B", "b"], ["C", "c"]]),include_blank: true, :onchange => "this.form.submit()" %>
<% end %>

<% if @model %>
     <% case @model %>
      <% when "a" %>
        do work 
      <% when "b" %>
        do work
      <% when "c" %>
        do work
     <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

where YY and XX are controller/method which render this view.

Controller:

```
def XX
   if params.has_key?(:report)
     @model = params[:report]
   end
end
```

**Please review**