# Using select_tag instead of link_to for ajax in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my dashboard `index.html.erb` view I have several links for an ajax call:

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>       
  <%= link_to employee.full_name, employee_details_path(:assigned_user_id => employee.assigned_user_id), remote: true, class: "employee-select" %></br>        
<% end %>
```

Clicking on that link renders a partial.

**dashboard_controller.rb**

```
def employee_details
  @latest_report = Report.where(:assigned_user_id => params[:assigned_user_id])
end
```

**employee_details.js.erb**

```
$('#employee-details').html("<%= escape_javascript (render partial: 'employee_details') %>");
```

What I want now is to instead of having several links that call the ajax when clicked, I want a select_tag that calls the ajax. Something like:

```
<%= select_tag "employees", options_from_collection_for_select(@employees, "assigned_user_id", "full_name"),
                                      :prompt => "Please select an employee",
                                      :onchange => "call ajax and render partial" %>
```

I am totally stuck at the moment.

Comment: You can just write am ajax method and that in onchange like `:onchange => "ajax-method-name();"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails select\_tag onchange ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948913/rails-select-tag-onchange-ajax-request)