# while population sub category dropdown receive below error active admin

Tags: ajax, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-6

Error:-

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template admin/blogs/get_child_category, active_admin/resource/get_child_category, active_admin/base/get_child_category, inherited_resources/base/get_child_category, application/get_child_category with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :vtt, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :mp3, :ogg, :m4a, :webm, :mp4, :otf, :ttf, :woff, :woff2, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :arb, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/rakesh/Documents/codetoart-website/app/views"
```

admin/category.rb

```
 form do |f|
    f.inputs do

       .....

      f.input :Category,:input_html => {
        :onchange => remote_request(:post, :get_child_category, {:child_category_id=>"$('#blog_category_id').val()"}, :child_category_id)
      }
      f.input :child_category_id
       .....
    end
    f.actions
  end
```

method:-

```
 controller do
    def get_child_category
      @child_category = Category.where(:parent_id => params[:child_category_id])
      render :text=>view_context.options_from_collection_for_select(@child_category, :id, :name)
    end
  end
```

application_helper.rb

```
 def remote_request(type, path, params={}, target_tag_id)
        "$.#{type}('#{path}',
                   {#{params.collect { |p| "#{p[0]}: #{p[1]}" }.join(", ")}},
                   function(data) {$('##{target_tag_id}').html(data);}
         );"
    end
```

is there any solution?
as it's not population sub category dropdown.

Comment: This looks very similar to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11948913/rails-select-tag-onchange-ajax-request`

Comment: It's easy if we use regular erb but I need help in case of active_admin

Comment: You seem close with `onchange: remote_request...` What difference between ERB and ARB is giving you trouble? Worst case you can render an ERB partial instead of ARB.