# Active admin parent child drop down creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, activeadmin

```
active_admin.rb
```

Is there a way to fill data in child drop-down if I select some value in self-associated parent drop-down.

Suppose I have a category and a child category self-association.

Now if I select any value form parent drop-down then child drop-down should be populated with only those values that are associated with the parent category.

Kindly let me know how I can implement this.

Comment: Can you add more details like your code where you are selecting this dropdown etc.?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60700802/while-population-sub-category-dropdown-receive-below-error-active-admin?noredirect=1#comment107436437_60700802 please review this link